# Is there a new mini-game in HOTS?

Tags: starcraft-2

After quickly glancing at the achievements before heading to work this morning, I didn't find any achievements that would indicate that a new mini-game has been introduced in Heart of the Swarm.

I'm wondering if there is indeed a new mini-game. In Wings of Liberty there was the "The Lost Viking" arcade cabinet, which would let you play that little top down shooter which was quite enjoyable.

If possible, don't include spoilers in your answer, as I've yet to indulge in the single player campaign just yet.

Comment: People can include spoilers in an answer by starting with ">!" before the text they want to hide. I don't really like the spoiler markup for many reasons, [one of which is that it doesn't work well if you're viewing the site on an iPad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129343/cannot-view-spoilers-on-ipad-when-logged-in), but I'd rather see that than see an answer left in an "incomplete" version for fear of spoilers.

Comment: Cool to know there is a spoiler markup! I seriously doubt they'll be any spoilers related to the mini-game though. :]

Comment: There's been much discussion on the forums regarding a HOTS minigame. People have made suggestions (loved "Angry Zergs"), but there's no information anywhere I can see, on the forums or otherwise, about an actual minigame.

You're not the only one wondering; you can look as some threads [**here**](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/3082028812) (very old thread) and  [**here**](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/7923494254).

It's only been a day essentially, so we'll find out soon enough.

Comment: Don't think that answers your question, so I'll leave it as a comment. Hope it helps though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having completed the campaign and like you gone through the achievements I will say there is no mini-game in Heart of the Swarm campaign like "the Lost Viking" in Wings of Liberty.

Answer (score 5):

**There aren't any minigames in HotS** similar to *SC2: WoL*, but there are Zerg evolution "mini" missions between missions.  Completing all of them gives you an achievement.